# How can I make my SearchView remember previous searches like how it is in the Play Market?

Tags: android, searchview

I want a drop down to display under the search view when clicked containing a list of previous searches

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.categories, menu);
        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
        .getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search All Categories");

        final AppListAdapter adapterAllApps = new AppListAdapter(
                CategoryListActivity.this, R.layout.app_row, catList);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a

```
AutoCompleteTextView
```

to do this and then add a searchable content provider.

have a look at this :

[Turn AutoCompleteTextView into a SearchView in ActionBar instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491515/turn-autocompletetextview-into-a-searchview-in-actionbar-instead)

Comment: I already have that. My autocomplete works fine now except for history. I need to know how to get it to show the previously searched terms

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510169/keep-different-search-histories-for-different-activities